# Adding parent ids to set in trigger

Tags: apex

How to refer Grand_Parent__c field in below if condition? I am trying to add parent ids to a collection type `Set<>`. But `childObj.Parent__r.Grand_Parent__c` value is not taking from grand parent though I have provided parent and grand parent values while testing manually.

```
public static void updateParent(List<Child__c>  childList){
        Map<ID, Parent__c> listLoan = new Map<ID, Parent__c>(); 
        List<Id> parentsetIds = new List<Id>();
        for (Child__c childObj : childList) {
            if(childObj.Parent__c != NULL && childObj.Parent__r.Grand_Parent__c != NULL){
                   parentsetIds.add(childObj.Parent__c); // here parentsetIds not taking childObj.Parent__r.Grand_Parent__c
               }
        }       
       // some logic
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Triggers do not populate referenced objects, only the immediate fields of the objects themselves.

You, therefore, will need to execute a query to bulk load all the parent objects to access the grand parent details, like:

```
Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();

for (Child__c child : childList) {
    parentIds.add(child.Parent__c);
}

List<Parent__c> parents = [SELECT Id, Grand_Parent__c WHERE Id IN :parentIds AND Grand_Parent__c != NULL];

Map<Id, Parent__c> parentsById = new Map<Id, Parent__c>(parents);

// This is a set of all parents for the children that have a grandparent
parentIds = parentsById.keySet();
```